# Голосовое управление

Tags: android

Всем добра! Ребят, нужна Ваша помощь. Я хочу добавить голосовое управление в приложении. Возможно ли это вообще? Если да, то что использовать и с чего начать вообще? Буду рад любым советам!

Comment: Возможно разными способами, можно API подтянуть, есть либы разные которые можно вшить, просто вопрос то огромный. Какая задача? Нажать кнопочку - сказать: "Закрыть приложение" и приложение должно закрыться?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei именно такая задача для начала:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте начать с [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/).

Есть [примеры использования на Java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/speech).

На последнем Google I/O [был доклад, на котором показывали робота, управляемого голосом.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpPyhsC4q9M) Ну и вообще на YouTube туториалов уже много.